# Python with PySDL2 - could not find any library for SDL2

Tags: python, import, environment-variables, pysdl2

I'm starting to use PySDL2 with Python 3.4 to make a game. Every time I run the "hello world" code given by the PySDL2 documentation it looks like I haven't installed the SDL library:

```
ImportError: could not find any library for SDL2 (PYSDL2_DLL_PATH: unset)
```

I have already tried to make a batch file to set the environment var:

```
set PYTHONPATH=C:\path\to\pysdl2\:$PYTHONPATH
```

and also tried to set the environment var through IDLE:

```
os.environ["PYSDL2_DLL_PATH"] = "path"
```

AND I've tried to even put the SDL.dll file in the System32 folder (btw I'm in a Windows x64 machine)
I need help, so if you can't answer because there's not enough information just tell me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SDL.dll does not sound like the correct DLL. Did you really download ***SDL2***, not SDL? If so, you can put ***SDL2.dll*** into a directory of your choice and let your environment point to it:

```
os.environ["PYSDL2_DLL_PATH"] = "c:\\directory\of\\sdl2\\library"
```

This has to be done *before* any `import sdl2...`   statement occurs.

Or you put the DLL file into the System32 folder.

You also should make sure that your Python installation matches the SDL2 build. If you use a 32-bit *SDL2.dll*, Python also must be a 32-bit build. If you use a 64-bit *SDL2.dll*, Python also must be a 64-bit build.

http://pysdl2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/faq.html and http://pysdl2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/install.html contain some more pointers.

Answer (score 5):

Actually what you need to do, is to have dll, so just pip install it

```
pip install pysdl2-dll
```

Answer (score 0):

For me the SDL2.dll file was found in this directory:

C:\Users\USERNAMWE\anaconda3\pkgs\sdl2-2.0.10-h6538335_0\Library\bin